# Simple error for someone who knows prolog. There is no fullstop to be causing the error

Tags: prolog

```
likes(a,b).
likes(b,d).
likes(c,e).
likes(d,f).
likes(e,h).

likes_trans(X,Y) :- likes(X,Z),likes_trans(Z,Y).
likes_trans(X,Y) :- likes(X,Y).
listfriends(X,R) :- findall(Y,likes_trans(X,Y),R).
likes_both(X,Y,R) := listfriends(X,P), listfriends(Y,S), member(R,P), member(S,P).
```

Why does the last line 'likes_both' give me the error (when loading the file)

> Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine

Any suggestions much appreciated, I know I'm missing something fundamental here.

Comment: Did you mean to put `:-` in place of `:=` there?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yup, fundamental that is ;) well spotted.

Comment: Awesome thank you,  I am embarrassed enough to say that I must be blind.

Comment: What is wrong with this site that someone would vote down a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `:=` on the last line should be replaced with `:-`

```
likes_both(X,Y,R) :- listfriends(X,P), listfriends(Y,S), member(R,P), member(S,P).
/*  Here ---------^^ */
```